Swift 6 `consuming` keyword causes compilation error
Related.
I'm trying to use the new consuming keyword while attempting to rewrite our codebase to Swift 6:
1.  Apple Swift version 6.0.2 (swiftlang-6.0.2.1.2 clang-1600.0.26.4)
2.  Compiling with the current language version
3.  While evaluating request ExecuteSILPipelineRequest(Run pipelines { Mandatory Diagnostic Passes + Enabling Optimization Passes } on SIL for PushNotificationServiceExtension)
4.  While running pass #615 SILFunctionTransform "MoveOnlyTypeEliminator" on SILFunction "@$s32PushNotificationServiceExtension0bC0C011setupCustomB4Task33_8D4DCFB31FB634FB0683A4519898C954LL8imageUrl18bestAttemptContent14contentHandlery10Foundation3URLV_So09UNMutablebR0CnySo014UNNotificationR0CcntFyyYaKcfU_".
 for expression at [/Users/home/project/iOS/PushNotificationServiceExtension/NotificationService.swift:73:10 - line:81:5] RangeText="{
      let (location, _) = try await URLSession.shared.download(from: imageUrl)
      let desiredLocation = URL(fileURLWithPath: "\(location.path)\(imageUrl.lastPathComponent)")

      try FileManager.default.moveItem(at: location, to: desiredLocation)
      let attachment = try UNNotificationAttachment(identifier: imageUrl.absoluteString, url: desiredLocation, options: nil)
      bestAttemptContent.attachments = [attachment]
      contentHandler(bestAttemptContent)
    "
Stack dump without symbol names (ensure you have llvm-symbolizer in your PATH or set the environment var `LLVM_SYMBOLIZER_PATH` to point to it):
0  swift-frontend           0x00000001066c29ac llvm::sys::PrintStackTrace(llvm::raw_ostream&, int) + 56
1  swift-frontend           0x00000001066c0c00 llvm::sys::RunSignalHandlers() + 112
2  swift-frontend           0x00000001066c2f78 SignalHandler(int) + 292
3  libsystem_platform.dylib 0x000000018a946584 _sigtramp + 56
4  swift-frontend           0x0000000101ea251c swift::SILInstructionVisitor<(anonymous namespace)::SILMoveOnlyWrappedTypeEliminatorVisitor, bool>::visitAllocPackInst(swift::AllocPackInst*) + 40
5  swift-frontend           0x0000000101ea1b8c (anonymous namespace)::SILMoveOnlyWrappedTypeEliminatorPass::run() + 5144
6  swift-frontend           0x0000000101eae988 swift::SILPassManager::runFunctionPasses(unsigned int, unsigned int) + 3448
7  swift-frontend           0x0000000101eaaf6c swift::SILPassManager::executePassPipelinePlan(swift::SILPassPipelinePlan const&) + 11968
8  swift-frontend           0x0000000101ee44b8 swift::SimpleRequest<swift::ExecuteSILPipelineRequest, std::__1::tuple<> (swift::SILPipelineExecutionDescriptor), (swift::RequestFlags)1>::evaluateRequest(swift::ExecuteSILPipelineRequest const&, swift::Evaluator&) + 56
9  swift-frontend           0x0000000101ec7e1c swift::ExecuteSILPipelineRequest::OutputType swift::Evaluator::getResultUncached<swift::ExecuteSILPipelineRequest, swift::ExecuteSILPipelineRequest::OutputType swift::evaluateOrFatal<swift::ExecuteSILPipelineRequest>(swift::Evaluator&, swift::ExecuteSILPipelineRequest)::'lambda'()>(swift::ExecuteSILPipelineRequest const&, swift::ExecuteSILPipelineRequest::OutputType swift::evaluateOrFatal<swift::ExecuteSILPipelineRequest>(swift::Evaluator&, swift::ExecuteSILPipelineRequest)::'lambda'()) + 412
10 swift-frontend           0x0000000101eca598 swift::runSILDiagnosticPasses(swift::SILModule&) + 612
11 swift-frontend           0x0000000101440fc4 swift::CompilerInstance::performSILProcessing(swift::SILModule*) + 84
12 swift-frontend           0x000000010106bcb0 performCompileStepsPostSILGen(swift::CompilerInstance&, std::__1::unique_ptr<swift::SILModule, std::__1::default_delete<swift::SILModule>>, llvm::PointerUnion<swift::ModuleDecl*, swift::SourceFile*>, swift::PrimarySpecificPaths const&, int&, swift::FrontendObserver*) + 1376
13 swift-frontend           0x000000010106aebc swift::performCompileStepsPostSema(swift::CompilerInstance&, int&, swift::FrontendObserver*) + 984
14 swift-frontend           0x000000010106e174 performCompile(swift::CompilerInstance&, int&, swift::FrontendObserver*) + 1684
15 swift-frontend           0x000000010106cea0 swift::performFrontend(llvm::ArrayRef<char const*>, char const*, void*, swift::FrontendObserver*) + 3572
16 swift-frontend           0x0000000100ff3f64 swift::mainEntry(int, char const**) + 3680
17 dyld                     0x000000018a58b154 start + 2476
Command SwiftCompile failed with a nonzero exit code

The code:
  private func downloadImageTask(
    imageUrl: URL,
    bestAttemptContent: consuming UNMutableNotificationContent,
    contentHandler: consuming @escaping (UNNotificationContent) -> Void
  ) {
    self.setupImageTask = Task {
      let (location, _) = try await URLSession.shared.download(from: imageUrl)
      let desiredLocation = URL(fileURLWithPath: "\(location.path)\(imageUrl.lastPathComponent)")
      
        try FileManager.default.moveItem(at: location, to: desiredLocation)
        let attachment = try UNNotificationAttachment(identifier: imageUrl.absoluteString, url: desiredLocation, options: nil)
      bestAttemptContent.attachments = [attachment]
      contentHandler(bestAttemptContent)
    }
  }

Any clue?
